# filter types for background color using css

Tags: css

i want set background color with two colors. in  tag at left and right to white color and at center main color

Comment: Why not just 1) make three elements, float them and give each its own color, or 2) give this element a background image?

Answer (score 1):

In css2 you should use different elements to be colored (why not divs?). so solution would come from html rather than from css. If you want to use only css, then you should look at css3 gradients, although css3 is not cross-browser-friendly solution.

Comment: In other words, if it's essential to your design, don't use css3, if it's just fancy color festing, then use it and ignore browsers who live in the last decade.

Answer (score 1):

you could use gradient. Here an css example:

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    right bottom,
    color-stop(0.2, rgb(255,255,255)),
    color-stop(0.5, rgb(36,171,74)),
    color-stop(0.8, rgb(255,255,255))
);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    left center,
    rgb(255,255,255) 20%,
    rgb(36,171,74) 50%,
    rgb(255,255,255) 80%
);
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/uwefe4

This will work for [Gecko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28layout_engine%29) and [webkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) browser engines.

To support internet explorer you can use a script like [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/).